# Nfsen install issue

Tags: netflow

Does someone else have issues with nfsen installation on CentOS 6.7?
Every package needed is installed but I still have an error:

```
<i>[root@eog nfsen-1.3.8]# ./install.pl etc/nfsen.conf 
Check for required Perl modules: All modules found.
Setup NfSen:
Version: 1.3.8: $Id: install.pl 71 2017-01-19 16:16:21Z peter $

Perl to use: [/usr/bin/perl] 
Setup php and html files.

Copy NfSen dirs etc bin libexec plugins doc ...
Copy config file 'etc/nfsen.conf'

In directory: /data/nfsen/libexec ...
Update script: AbuseWhois.pm
Update script: Log.pm
Update script: Lookup.pm
Update script: NfAlert.pm
Update script: Nfcomm.pm
Update script: NfConf.pm
Update script: NfProfile.pm
Update script: NfSen.pm
Update script: NfSenRC.pm
Update script: NfSenRRD.pm
Update script: NfSenSim.pm
Update script: Nfsources.pm
Update script: Nfsync.pm
Update script: Notification.pm
In directory: /data/nfsen/bin ...
Update script: nfsen
Update script: nfsend
Update script: RebuildHierarchy.pl
Update script: testPlugin

Cleanup old files ...

Setup diretories:

Use UID/GID 500 48
Exists: /data/nfsen/var
Exists: /data/nfsen/var/tmp
Exists: /data/nfsen/var/run
Exists: /data/nfsen/var/filters
Exists: /data/nfsen/var/fmt
Exists: /data/nfsen/profiles-stat
Exists: /data/nfsen/profiles-stat/live
Exists: /data/nfsen/profiles-data
Exists: /data/nfsen/profiles-data/live

Profile live: spool directories:
Exists: stream1
Rename gif RRDfiles ... done.
RRD DB 'stream1.rrd' already exists!
Use existing profile info for profile 'live'

Rebuilding profile stats for './live'
Can't use string ("live") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at libexec/NfProfile.pm line 1238.</i>
```

code of message I get when try to install nfsen from soruce....

Does anyone have an idea how to solve issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# ./install.pl **./**etc/nfsen.conf
```